# Why does my random function return the same value twice

Tags: javascript

Context: I was creating a dummy website with some dummy Graphs. I needed some random value in similar js objects like this:

```
object = {
  x: static,
  y: static,
  ...

  data: random
}
```

So I came up with something like this:

```js
async function getOption() {
  return getRandom();
}

async function setup() {
  let template = {
    static1: "xx",
    static2: "xx",
    option: 1
  }

  let v1 = template;
  v1.option = await getOption();

  let v2 = template;
  v2.option = await getOption();

  console.log(await getOption(), await getOption())
  console.log(v1.option, v2.option)

}

function getRandom() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

setup()
```

But I've noticed something strange that I don't understand. I get the same "random" value twice every time if I want to assign a new number. Furthermore, if I call it inside a `console.log()`, it works as expected.

Now my Questions:

N° 1: How can I create a lot of big Objects with the same attribute except 1?

N° 2: Why do I get the same Value twice? It doesn't really make sense to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1 and v2 are just references to the template object. Essentially, v1 and v2 are the same. Look at the console here. v1 is a random value and v2 is also random, but it is overridden by v2:

```js
async function getOption() {
  return getRandom();
}

async function setup() {
  let template = {
    static1: "xx",
    static2: "xx",
    option: 1
  }

  let v1 = template;
  v1.option = await getOption();
  
  console.log('v1:', v1.option)
  console.log('template:', template.option)


  let v2 = template;
  v2.option = await getOption();
  
  console.log('v2:', v2.option)
  console.log('template:', template.option)


  console.log(v1.option, v2.option)

}

function getRandom() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

setup()
```

EDIT: If you wanted to make copies, you could use `assign()`:

```js
let template = {
  static1: "xx",
  static2: "xx",
  option: 1
}


var obj = Object.assign({}, template);

template.option = "100"
obj.option = "200"

console.log(template.option, obj.option)
```

Comment: I did not know that this doesn't copy the object but references it. Thank you. This works for me

Comment: @Bolphgolph No problem. It can be a bit confusing when the code makes sense but the output doesn't :P

Comment: @Bolphgolph see my edit which addresses your first question.

Answer (score 1):

You have `v1=template;` and `v2=template;`, so v1 and v2 are the same object.

If you want to copy template, use

```
v1 = {...template};
v2 = {...template};
```